# Suddenly stops working without editing - AutoFilter method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code where I am selecting two dates to filter the data in between. It worked fine, I was using it multiple times to keep finding error in other part of the code but suddenly it starts appearing the error "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

Here is part of the code

```
Sub StartEnd()
Dim StDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

 StDate = Application.Workbooks("Report 1st Stage").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K8")
 EndDate = Application.Workbooks("Report 1st Stage").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K9")

Dim StartDate As Date: StartDate = Format(StDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Dim EDate As Date: EDate = Format(EndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")


'It throws the error here
Application.Workbooks("Report 1st Stage").Worksheets("Hrs Worked").Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EDate
Application.Workbooks("Report 1st Stage").Worksheets("Pareto Summary").Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EDate
Application.Workbooks("Report 1st Stage").Worksheets("Trend Analysis").Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EDate
```

Comment: If the VBA didn't change, then the worksheet probably did. Maybe it is conflicting with some other autofilter that is already applied.

Comment: I am clearing the filter everytime it ends, so i dont know.

Comment: Maybe nothing matches the criteria. Maybe the formatting of cells have changed so the entries are no longer treated as dates. The code works for me unless I run it with a column that doesn't contain a date in the target range. It is hard to do anything more than guess.

Comment: I really dont know what happened. I get desperate (laughing), erased the workbook and paste the whole code again. It's working again.